# The binded select value from ngModel in not shown on default

Tags: html, angular, data-binding

I have two select elements in this Angular 4 app where I use ngModel to bind selected options to two fields.
However only one is displaying the default value.

When I debug the one not working I can see that ng-reflect-model is set to the correct value, but the option is not shown in UI...
[image]
[image]

If I remove the select element which is working, then the other one is working.

First select: `<select [(ngModel)]="registration.fromTerminal" name="location" class="custom-input" required id="terminal">
              <option *ngFor="let depot of depots" [ngValue]="depot.departmentCode">
                {{depot.departmentCode + ' ' + depot.departmentName}}
              </option>
            </select>`

Second select:`<select [(ngModel)]="registration.toTerminal" name="location" class="custom-input" required id="toTerminal">
              <option *ngFor="let depot of unmarkedDepots" [ngValue]="depot.departmentCode">
                {{depot.departmentCode + ' ' + depot.departmentName}}
              </option>
            </select>`

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Comment: Yes, I will do it tomorrow.

Comment: @Jens you're using same name for both select tags. Just change them to something different. I believe that's the issue. If the problem remains, please provide a stackblitz.

Comment: You are right, thank you so much! Can't belive I didn't see that.

Should I delete this question as it is only caused by a mistake of mine, or should I keep if other makes the same mistake?